# Cache Issue / User See Homepage News from 1 month ago

Tags: caching, browser, varnish, w3-total-cache

I'm not a tecnichian, I own a website based on wordpress, with W3 Cache, on Apache Server, and we used to have Varnish Cache acrtivated. We launched a new version of the site some weeks ago, and then we had a loss of visitors. Some of them connected to facebook page, gave me a feedback and screenshot of my homepage stuck on news from 3 weeks ago on their browser. The problem is not showing everywhere, lot of my friends actually see the updated news on my homepage. 
We deactivated the varnish cache, and the browser cache without result, yesterday another user sent me a screenshot with old news.

We are quite desperate and we don't know what's the problem on our site.

My website is http://www.rnbjunk.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a strange caching header:

```
    Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Thus, some clients will not ask for a fresh version of the page and serve the content to the user using the browser cache.